# Comparator vs Comparable for sorting

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

Comparator vs Comparable has various posts and content available online to understands. But I couldnt understand. Its my first time I'm trying to undertsnad this. So please bear with me.

After reading alot, was checking this eaxmple to understand

```
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/
```

And came into one doubt that, the sorting which is being done by `Comparable` implementing class, can also perform same kind of sorting which is being done `Comparator` implementing class in above example.

At then end, sorting is being done by comparison between two objects.

So Any example, Which could really stanbds out and says that's a real difference.

Any help please...?

Comment: A compara**tor** is a thing which compares two other things. A compar**able** is a thing which can be compared to another thing.

Comment: @Michael, At the end, all items are in list and gets compared in between two objects in some order. Then what's a point ..?

Comment: Sometimes the item you want to sort has a natural ordering. Numbers have a natural ordering, strings have a natural ordering (alphabetical). In this case, compar**able** makes sense, and you can bake this functionality right into the class. Sometimes the item you want to sort does not have a natural ordering. Say you want to sort a list of movies. A movie could be sorted by release date, by revenue, by title, the list goes on. In such case, it makes sense to implement this externally as a compar**ator**, following the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Comment: @Michael, If even its sorted by release date, by revenue, by title, at the end sorting happens on the basis of -1 or 0 return by the method, so it can be done in Comparable too..! No..?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you, but what if you want to sort movies by release date first, then sort by title in some other code? You can't implement `Comparable` twice, but you can create two `Comparator`s. Conceptually, `Comparable` should be used when there is a clear and obvious natural ordering, and `Comparator` should be used when there isn't.

Comment: @Michael Now it makes sense..! Thanks boy ..! :)